# Blank row issue while splitting PDF page using itext

Tags: java, itext

I have a itext PDFPTable which contains a List of data to be displayed. Since the data size is large , it is split into two pages. While displaying the records for the next page the first row always appears blank(Or may be it is the last row of previous page which is extended to the next page). Has any one faced this issue, then please help here.
I tried with 
table.setSplitLate(true); 
with this the 1st row of the next page is coming properly but Last row of the 1st page is expanded a bit. Can any one suggest any solution.
Below is the  code Snippet I am using

```
PdfPTable table = //create a standard table //
            table.setSplitLate(false);
            table.setSplitRows(true);
            table.addCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);

PdfPTable detailTable = //create a standard table //    
            detailTable.setWidths(new float[] {25,25,25,25});
            detailTable.setWidthPercentage(100); 
            detailTable.setHeaderRows(1);
            detailTable.setSplitLate(false);
            detailTable.setSplitRows(true);     
           BaseColor color;
           int count=1;  
                 //Table header
                 detailTable.addCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                 detailTable.addCell(//createTextCell//);
                  detailTable.addCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                 detailTable.addCell(//createTextCell//);
                  detailTable.addCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                 detailTable.addCell(//createTextCell//);
                  detailTable.addCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                 detailTable.addCell(//createTextCell//);
                //Populating Table values
               for(Class Data : dummyList){
                 count++;
                 if(count%2==0) color= alternateColor;
                 else color = pageColor;
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createEmptyTableCell(//createEmptyTableCell//);
                    detailTable.addCell(PdfCell.createTextCell(//Some Values//);
               }  

        table.addCell(PdfCell.createTableCell(detailTable,1, false, pageColor));
```

Basically detailtable is added to the Main table.And Details Table holds a list .The List size is large so it is Split into 2 pages. The Pages looks like below. Page looks good , but a blank row appears on the 1st row of next page

Sample Image

[image]

I am using I-text -5.5.3

Comment: I've seen this in obsolete versions of iText. I can't reproduce this with new versions of iText. Your question isn't specific enough. We don't know what your code looks like. We don't know which version of iText you're using.

Comment: I am usingg Itext 5.5.3. Please see the below code I am using